# We can't find products matching the selection - M2.4.2

Tags: category-products, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2

In my website some times category page shows "We can't find products matching the selection." When i run `"indexer:reindex"`

it shows

`Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cl`

Every time i'm restart the server to clear the error. I need a permanent solution to clear this error.

Comment: did you get elasticsearch error?

Comment: execute below commands and restart your elasticsearch.

Comment: Now i execute below command it display "{"acknowledged":true}". Let me confirm this error will not come next time?

Comment: also check your elasticsearch status and port

Comment: I had checked for 9200 elasticsearch port.

Comment: When i check status of elasticsearch, it shows "Failed to start Elasticsearch."

Answer (score 1):

may be your elasticsearch not working.

execute below commands

```
sudo curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'

sudo curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```